# React-Select how to keep default behavior of menu open/close plus add to open menu on button click?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I have a react-select component to preform search on an api , and a button to start the search.

i've tried to set menuIsOpen={true} after button click but it ruins the original focus blur behavior the menu is no longer closing on blur.
tried to set .focus() on the input it didn't open the menu.

current original behavior menu is opening on focus and closing on blur , i want to keep this plus i want to open the menu after i click the button.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve what you want you will need to use a controlled `menuIsOpen` props.

I think the easiest way to keep all the native functionality of `react-select` is to use a combination of the props `onInputChange` and `onFocus` like the following code:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      menuIsOpen: false
    };
  }

  onInputChange = (options, { action }) => {
    if (action === "menu-close") {
      this.setState({ menuIsOpen: false });
    }
  };

  openMenu = () => {
    this.refs.focus();
    this.setState({ menuIsOpen: true });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <Select
          ref={r => {
            this.refs = r;
          }}
          options={options}
          onFocus={this.openMenu}
          onInputChange={this.onInputChange}
          menuIsOpen={this.state.menuIsOpen}
        />

        <button onClick={this.openMenu}>Open Select</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Here a [live example](https://codesandbox.io/s/8kxx492138).

Comment: @TITAN9389 I have updated my code to add some `ref` and focused the menu when clicking on the button

Comment: thanks i've already did it my self thats why deleted the comment , thanks anyways.

Comment: You need to `this.refs.blur()` too on `onInputChange` close

Comment: In your example and live demo, the default behavior of opening and closing menu directly with the select doesn't work anymore

Comment: Works perfectly on my side

Answer (score 2):

If you want to preserve the focus out behaviour you should do something like this
add a ref at the constructor

```
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = { open: false }
        this.selectRef = React.createRef();
    }
```

then add this close method

```
close() {
        this.setState({ open: false });
        this.selectRef.current.blur();
    }
```

and on the select component

```
<Select
    closeMenuOnSelect={props.closeMenuOnSelect || true}
    openMenuOnClick={() => this.setState({ open: true })}
    onFocus={() => this.setState({ open: true })}
    onBlur={() => this.setState({ open: false })}
    menuIsOpen={this.state.open}
    onInputChange={() => {
        if (props.closeMenuOnSelect) {
        this.close();
    }
    }}
    ref={this.selectRef}
    >
</Select>
```

Answer (score 1):

This option is good option without managing the state.

```
openMenuOnFocus={true}
```

This also work on tab button click because when click on tab button then dropdown have the focus.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this function in React, to keep open only one tab, so as you open another one, previous will be closed.

```
const openSingleTab = (id) => {
    const newData1 = data.map((item) => {
        if(item.id === id){
          return {...item, isOpened: !item.isOpened}
        }
        return {...item, isOpened: false}
      })

    setData(newData1)
  }
```